# uniform convergence on [0, 1]

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

determine whether $f_n (x) = \frac {x}  {1+nx^2}$ defines the sequence of functions $\{f_n\} _{n\in N}$ converging uniformly on [0, 1]?

My take on this question:

First, I determined the pointwise on this function which is ${f_n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and then I found $M_n = sup{|f_n (x) - f(x)|} = \frac {1/ \sqrt(n)}{1+n/\sqrt n}$. Therefore the sequence of functions converge to [0,1] uniformly as $M_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

I am not sure if my answer and/or approach is correct. If someone can please verify for me, please?

Thank You in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator of $f'_n (x) $ is

$$1+nx^2-2nx^2=1-nx^2$$

the maximum $M_n $  is attained at $x=1/\sqrt {n} .$

but $$M_n=\frac {1}{2\sqrt {n}}\to 0$$ thus the convergence is uniform at $[0,1] $.

Comment: just a side note/question: max $M_n$ is attained at the highest x value alwaya, right?

Comment: @ISuckAtMathPleaseHELPME The extremum is attained where the derivative is zero.